# Detecting if the win7 desktop is shown with python and Qt

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, win32gui, hwnd

I want to check if the desktop of Windows 7 is shown (e.g. after clicking control+D or the showDesktop-Button).

It is meant for an application where I've set the QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint to make the decorations disappear. After the desktop is shown and everything is minimized, I want to reshow the app (This should be optional and the user can set or unset this behaviour).

I tested this in IDLE. I want to detect a change if I show the desktop, but still there is the "1" printed. Only if I close(destroy) the window, it changes to "0", but thats not what I am searching for...

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import sys
import win32gui
import time

class Main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, app):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.app=app
        self.window=QWidget()
        self.window.resize(200,100)
        self.window.setWindowTitle("Dummy")
        #self.window.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.window.show()

        self.check_Minimized_Thread=Worker(self)

        self.check_Minimized_Thread.start()

        self.app.exec_()

class Worker(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        self.exiting = False

    def __del__(self):
        self.exiting = True
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        while True:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            hwnd=win32gui.FindWindow(None,"Dummy")
            A=win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd)
            print(A)

        self.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    Main(app)
```